# Do surahs [An-Nisaa 4:140]. [Al An'aam 6:68]. and [Al-Furqan 25:72] also apply to imagining and recalling wrong and false beliefs?

Tags: quran, fiqh, sin

Assalamualaikum we rahmatullahi we barakatuhu.   It is not permissible to sit with, or watch and listen to, those who are establishing disbeliefs or wrong and false beliefs.[An-Nisaa 4:140]. [Al An'aam 6:68]. and [Al-Furqan 25:72]

But my question is: Does this principle also apply to Imagining and recalling wrong and false beliefs like :  ?

Example: I can imagine someone prostrating to an idol even though I hate it in my heart as action but I remember in my mind a Hindu in Al Jazeera prostrating to an idol and I keep my mind without any necessity to that image. Or I can keep my mind imagining the sayings of a christian tv channel where he says all those wrong things about Isa Ibn Maryam.

Comment: If someone can answer this question please.

Comment: Give your personal opinion at least. As a muslim you should be interested for the fundamentals of islam from the first day you enter islam.